# PassWord checker, How to list all problems at once?

Tags: java, passwords

So recently I have been coding this password checker and I am nearly done. For my password checker there are a few requirements.

- Greater than 8 Characters
- Less than 20 Characters
- Must use a @ sign and a Underscore
- Must also contain a number and can not use a first or last name

I have successfully coded all of this now I just have write a code that will list all the requirements not met all at once and not one by one. Also when the password is acceptable and all requirements have been met. I Appreciate any help, Thanks Guys

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordChecker {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner james = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hi there, Welcome to Password Heavean where we have the hardest password combinations on this easrth and any other earth.");
    System.out.println("Take note your password must be longer than 8 and less than 20 characters, Can not have your first or last name, must use a @ sign, must have a number and use at leaast 3 capitals");
    System.out.println("First please input you first name.");
    String passWord;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String firstNameLower;
    String lastNameLower;
    String passWordLower;
    firstName = james.nextLine();
    firstNameLower = firstName.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("Also please input you Last name.");
    lastName = james.nextLine();
    lastNameLower = lastName.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("Please enter your password now");
    passWord = james.nextLine();
    passWordLower = passWord.toLowerCase();
    if (passWordLower.length() < 9) {
      while (passWordLower.length() > 20) {
        System.out.println("Sorry but your password is greater than or equal too 20 characters, please try a differnent password");
        passWord = james.nextLine();
      }
    }
    if (passWordLower.indexOf(firstNameLower) != -1 || (passWordLower.indexOf(lastNameLower) != -1)) {
      System.out.println("Sorry but you can not use your first or your last name in the password. ");
    }
    if (passWordLower.contains("@")) {} else {
      System.out.println("Sorry but you must use a @ symbol in your password.");
    }
    if (passWordLower.contains("_")) {} else {
      System.out.println("Sorry but you must use a underscore in your password.");
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < passWordLower.length(); i++) {
      if (Character.isDigit(passWordLower.charAt(i))) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
    if (counter < 3) {
      System.out.println("Sorry but you need to have at least 3 numbers in your password.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, still a little knew didnt know how to properly insert the code with it looking nice. But i dont think it looks too bad like that

Comment: `if (passWordLower.contains("@")) {} else {` can be replaced with `if (!passWordLower.contains("@")) {`

Comment: Use a string buffer and append all the messages to it in the if blocks, Print them all at once in the end.

Comment: Thanks, Shmosel. Saved me some extra and unneeded code

Comment: I think I could put one big while loop around it, but im not too sure about that.?

Comment: Your password length checking does not work at all like you want it to. Anything below 9 characters will pass, only 21+ character passwords are rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this ,

```
 StringBuffer errorMgs = new StringBuffer();

    errorMgs.append("Sorry !! ");

    if (passWordLower.length() < 9) {
        errorMgs.append("your password must have minimum 9 characters \nand");
    }
    else if (passWordLower.length() > 20) {
        errorMgs.append("your password is greater than or equal too 20 characters \nand");
    }
    if (passWordLower.indexOf(firstNameLower) != -1 || (passWordLower.indexOf(lastNameLower) != -1)) {
        errorMgs.append(" you can not use your first or your last name \nand");
    }
    if (!passWordLower.contains("@")) {
        errorMgs.append(" you must use a @ symbol \nand");

    }
    if (!passWordLower.contains("_")) {
        errorMgs.append(" you must use a underscore \nand");
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < passWordLower.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(passWordLower.charAt(i))) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter < 3) {
        errorMgs.append(" you need to have at least 3 numbers");
    }

    if (!errorMgs.toString().equals("Sorry !! ")) { //identify given password met all criterias or not   
        errorMgs.append(" in your password.");
        System.out.println(errorMgs);
    } else {
        System.out.println("your password accepted");
    }
```

And your out-put will be something like this ,

> Hi there, Welcome to Password Heavean where we have the hardest
>   password combinations on this easrth and any other earth. Take note
>   your password must be longer than 8 and less than 20 characters, Can
>   not have your first or last name, must use a @ sign, must have a
>   number and use at leaast 3 capitals
>
> First please input you first name.
>
> jhone
>
> Also please input you Last name.
>
> peter
>
> Please enter your password now
>
> sld4f
>
> Sorry !!  you must use a @ symbol  and you must use a underscore  and
>   you need to have at least 3 numbers in your password.

Comment: Just curious any way to get rid of the and and just have a new line?

Comment: then use `System.lineSeparator()` instead `\n`

Comment: i tried it but it didnt work when you went over 20 characters it glitched out.

Comment: I Feel like such a di** for asking anymore from you but if you have like 30 seconds dont waste time on it how could i allow the program to restart after they fail the password, where they can try again

Answer (score 0):

I also changed the if+while block with only while block

```
while (passWord.length() < 9 || passWord.length() > 20) {
  System.out.println("Sorry but your password is greater than or equal too 20 characters, please try a differnent password");
  passWord = james.nextLine();
}
passWordLower = passWord.toLowerCase();

String errorMessage = "";
if (passWordLower.indexOf(firstNameLower) != -1 || (passWordLower.indexOf(lastNameLower) != -1)) {
  errorMessage += "Sorry but you can not use your first or your last name in the password. " + System.lineSeparator();
}
if (passWordLower.contains("@")) {} else {
  errorMessage += "Sorry but you must use a @ symbol in your password." + System.lineSeparator();
}
if (passWordLower.contains("_")) {} else {
  errorMessage += "Sorry but you must use a underscore in your password." + System.lineSeparator();
}
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < passWordLower.length(); i++) {
  if (Character.isDigit(passWordLower.charAt(i))) {
    counter++;
  }
}
if (counter < 3) {
  errorMessage += "Sorry but you need to have at least 3 numbers in your password." + System.lineSeparator();
}

System.out.println(errorMessage);
```

I don't think you will notice the difference, it prints so fast